# Use field of class that implements Singleton pattern in another class

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns, singleton

I have a class `A` that implements the singleton pattern and contains `object obj`:

```
public sealed class A
{
    static A instance=null;
    static readonly object padlock = new object();
    public object obj;

    A()
    {
        AcquireObj();
    }

    public static A Instance
    {
        get
        {
            if (instance==null)
            {
                lock (padlock)
                {
                    if (instance==null)
                    {
                        instance = new A();
                    }
                }
            }
            return instance;
        }
    }

   private void AcquireObj()
   {
      obj = new object();
   }
}
```

Now I have another class B where I need to keep instance of A.obj object until it's alive.

```
public class B
{
    // once class A was instantiated, class B should have public A.obj
    // field available  to share.
    // what is the best way/practice of putting obj here? 
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Can't class B simply access A.Instance.obj? This will initialize A if it was not formerly initialized.

Comment: class A can't be initialized by class B. Class A has it's own way of initialization.

Comment: What do you mean by "it's own way of initialization"? Isn't it a Singleton?

Comment: I think you will have to use A.Instance.obj.  This way you are calling your static property which initialized the instance (if not already initialized) and gives the obj back to you.

Comment: Vadim, there is another place where class A should be instantiated, not in class B.

Comment: It's a Singleton. It should not matter *where* it is initialized.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make it like this:

```
class B
{
    public object obj
    {
        get
        {
            return A.Instance.obj;
        }
    }
}
```

If it's the first time anyone touches `A.Instance`, this will initialize it. On subsequent calls it will reuse the same instance of `A`.

Comment: looks good, Magnus, let me try it, was thinking about this way, just decided to double check if there is special way of doing that.